# Best way to change node value with libxml2

Tags: xml, linux, libxml2

I want to change the value of a node in a given XML file as template and save the entire XML as another file.

I must use the libxml2 library in a Linux environment and my ideas were:

- parse the template file
- when element found modify it
- save the document

Can be this workflow correct?

Are there other way to do this thing with less code?

Any code example will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to open the file in r/w mode, found the value and change it on the fly. But the problem is when the value is difficult to find.

The solution with libxml2 is to parse the file for creating a tree. The tree is a very good structure for finding a value.
You can change the value in the tree and save the tree in a new file.

Comment: In my question I was searching for a "libxml2 workflow" so, first solution cannot be valid. Second solution is good but is identical to mine so I cannot mark this answer as accepted. Anyway thank you for your answer!

Comment: I think there are no other solutions at the moment, so, accepted :)